# RabbitMQ Web STOMP without SockJS

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

Is it possible to setup RabbitMQ Web STOMP connection without SockJS library?

I have played around with `rabbitmq-web-stomp` plugin without a success as the initial response generated by the server is *`Welcome to SockJS!`* (which is obviously not a STOMP based message).

Is SockJS really required? What does it bring into the game (besides legacy browser support)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SockJS protocol [does support raw WebSocket clients](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#connecting-to-sockjs-without-the-client) under `/websocket` path.

> Any SockJS server complying with 0.3 protocol does support a raw WebSocket url. The raw WebSocket url for the test server looks like:
>
> ```
> ws://localhost:8081/echo/websocket
> ```
>
> You can connect any WebSocket RFC 6455 compliant WebSocket client to this url.

This is supported by Rabbit's implementation as well. So the default endpoint is: `http://example.com:15674/stomp/websocket`.

Comment: RabbitMq web stomp doesn't support websocket PING frame message — server doesn't send PONG frame back. It is the reason, why client.heartbeat.outgoing and client.heartbeat.incoming are set to 0 (see official examples — "SockJS does not support heart-beat: disable heart-beats").

So, your connection will be terminated by proxy or by stomp-websocket library (if you don't set client.heartbeat.* to 0).